# After building nsmutablearray should i convert it to nsarray for performance benefit?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Wondering, After building nsmutablearray should i convert it to nsarray for performance benefit? If i am going to keep and use that array for quite sometime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  The conversion itself will cost time and CPU cycles and you won't gain anything from the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually say it depends. If I create a NSMutableArray within a method and needs to return it, then generally unless the caller requires the ability to directly modify the array values, I will return the NSMutableArray as a NSArray for the sake of simlicity and to reduce the memory footprint of the application.

However, if I am creating the NSMutableArray for direct consumption within the current method, then I seen no benefit of casting it to a NSArray.

Comment: Casting it back from `NSMutableArray` to `NSArray` won't reduce memory footprint; the object will remain `NSMutableArray`, it's just that the caller won't know it (unless they actively try and find out).  Also who's to say `NSMutableArray` "costs" any more than `NSArray`?  I would doubt it.